# How exactly "make all" works?

Tags: c, unix, makefile, gnu-make

So I am studying makefiles usage. Let's say I 've many functions `fun_i.c` where i is in [1,100]. I have wrote them all in seperate .c files in order to make faster compilation when I only change some of them. I need to create a Makefile. I was thinking something like that:

```c
all : program
program: fun1.o fun2.o   ........ fun100.o main.o
         gcc -o program fun1.o fun2.o ..... fun100.o
fun1.o: fun1.c
        gcc -c fun1.c 
.
.
.
fun100.o: fun100.c 
          gcc -c fun100.c
main.o : main.c 
         gcc -c main.c
```

I 've read many articles online talking about how the target "all" makes sure that everytime I change something in a function and I call make it will update only what changes (so I'm going to avoid uneccessary recompilation).
However, I am not sure if I am using it right here. I checked my makefile ( with 2 functions though) and it worked fine. But I am not sure if that's the way to take advantage of `all` here.
I tried to remove it and just leave  `program` and below.. there and it worked as fine.
What am I missing?
Could you may provide examples that all is critical?

Comment: `all` is basically an alias for `program` in your makefile. There is no magic to the name `all`, it works just like any other name you could use.

Comment: Avoiding unnecessary recompilation is a general behavior of `make`, not a special function of any particular target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I 've read many articles online talking about how the target "all" makes sure that everytime I change something in a function and I call make it will update only what changes

`all` does not mean anything. It's just a convention. You have to define the targets correctly to do what you want. If you want `make all` to recompile everything, you need to define it so that it does that.

> so I'm going to avoid uneccessary recompilation

In practice, I'd say that this is a completely unnecessary concern, and it's a waste of time creating makefiles that does this. If you have a large project you should not create makefiles manually. You use a build system like cmake.

If the project is small and only contain a few files, then the compilation time is in general not an issue. For a small project, my goal with a makefile would be to not have to type the compiler flags all the time.

Here is a makefile that would work fine for most very small projects like school assignments:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c17 -fsanitize=address
LIBS=-lm -lpthread

program:
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) *.c

clean:
        rm -rf *.o *~
```

Comment: if I add this :             ```all : program``` and below it <tab> ``` make program ``` would it be any different from skipping the ```all``` target ?

Comment: No, it would not make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile is fine, both with and without `all: program`.

The word `all` has no special significance in makefiles, using is just a convention. In your makefile `all` has no recipe (i.e. no commands associated with it), so `make all` and `make program` are equivalent.

Note that if you don't specify a target when invoking Make (e.g. `make` as opposed to `make program`), the first target in the makefile is built.

Comment: if I put a recipe below ```all: program``` like ```make program``` it has no difference from just skipping all target and leaving `` program : f1.o ...``` ? THe only difference is that by writing all I simply rename my executable and I can insted of writing make program write make all? If i wanted to create 2 executables with one makefile would it make more sense to use ```all : program1 program2 ```?