# Binary is not rebuilding when source file changes

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

I have a directory structure like the following:

- Makefile

  - `bin`

    ```
      main.c
      Makefile
    ```
  - lib

    ```
      lib1.c
      lib2.c
      Makefile
    ```
  - tst

    ```
      test1.cc
      Makefile
    ```

In my Makfile I have code the looks like this:

```
ALL_OBJECTS = main.o lib1.o lib2.o
BINS = binary
binary,SRCS = main.o lib1.o lib2.o
OBJS = $($(*),SRCS)

all: $(ALL_OBJECTS) $(BINS)

%.o   : %.c
      ${CC} -c $^ -o $@
binary:
        ${CC} -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

My question is when I change and of the source files like main.c, lib1.c or lib2.c the *.o file is re-compiled during make but the binary is not recompiled. How can I ensure that the binary is recompiled when one of its dependencies change?

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but if you want to do anything non-trivial, then use Cmake or something similar instead of constructing Makefiles your own. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843225/6699433) is a related answer I wrote

Comment: your binary has no dependency on the .o objects

Comment: @klutt: In my experience, CMake is a bad idea a considerable amount of extra work unless you really need the cross-platform capabilities it provides.

Comment: Is there not a .d file I can create which outlines the dependencies for the binary?

Comment: Re. `"Is there not a .d file I can create which outlines the dependencies for the binary?"`: not as far as I'm aware.  `.d` files generally contain dependencies of an object file on sources and headers and can be generated by the compiler (see [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for example).  But linker dependencies need to be specified manually (I'd love to be proven wrong on this).

Comment: Sure, you can create a `.d` file if you want to do that rather than just writing the prerequisites in the makefile.  It seems like a lot of extra work but you can do it.  I suppose what you really wanted to know was, is there some way to automatically generate a dependencies file.  No.  `.d` files can be generated because the source file lists inside it the headers it requires and compiler finds them, so the compiler can generate the `.d` files.  But the compiler can't guess what object files might need to be used: you don't list that anywhere in your source files for example.

Comment: You can run make with the option `-d` to let it dump a lot of debugging information. I'm not sure that `binary,SRC = ...` does what you think it should...

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of your Makefile don't make much sense to me, and the directory structure you show doesn't really seem to match up well with the Makefile you show. For example, with a directory named `lib` that contains a Makefile of its own, I'd *expect* to see that Makefile create a library that depends on lib1.o and lib2.o. Then `binary` would depend on that library.

But right now, it looks like you're just building `binary` from a single Makefile, and ignoring the Makefile in the `lib` directory. That can work too, but it's going to be different from the previous scenario.

For the moment, let's start with a bit "flatter" directory structure, with `main.c`, `lib1.c` and `lib2.c` all contained in a single directory (and the Makefile in that same directory). For this case, we can build the binary with a really simple Makefile:

```
binary: lib1.o lib2.o main.o
   $(CC) -o binary lib1.o lib2.o main.o
```

We just make that the binary depends on the object files, and how to create the binary from those object files. Any reasonable modern make utility already has built-in rules for how to compile a .c file to produce a .o file, so we don't have to do any more than that unless we want something fairly unusual in how we build those object files.

That does repeat the names of the object files in two places though. We'd usually prefer to avoid that. We can separate out defining the names of the object files from the rule to make the binary from them, to get something more like this:

```
OBJS = lib1.o lib2.o main.o

binary: $(OBJS)
   $(CC) -o binary $(OBJS)
```

Now we only have the names of the object files in one place, so if (for one obvious example) we add another object file, we only need to add its name in one place, rather than two.

Comment: Yes., I simplified the Makefile for this example. I am trying to generate a rule such that I have a list of binaries which have .o files they depend on and it applies the same rule to compile them. I am trying to avoid multiple lines of binary1: $(OBJ1), binary2: $(OBJ2) binary3:$(OBJ3) .etc... Essentially all would be running the same CC -o $@ @^ command. This is while I omitted the dependencies from binary and calculate them in the command. I want a structure like: $(BIN_OUT)%:             CC -o $@ $($@,SRCS)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment to @JerryCoffin's answer, you could do something like this:

```
binary1 : lib1.o lib2.o main1.o
binary2 : lib2.o main2.o
binary3 : lib1.o main3.o

binary1 binary2 binary3:
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

The first three lines have no recipe, and thus simply are adding prerequisites to the associated binaries.   Then you define a recipe for the binary targets using the automatic variable `$^`, which will expand to that target's dependencies.